# Disabled custom action tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ribbon, custom-actions, sharepoint-hosted-app

Some custom actions in SharePoint display an additional message with possible reason of the action being disabled. Is there a simple way of adding such a message only when the action is disabled (for example a specific CAML property) or can it be achieved only using JavaScript/jQuery?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToolTipTitle` and  `ToolTipDescription` of the `Button` element in custom action.

Comment: But aren't tooltips displayed always when the action is pointed on, no matter whether it's disabled or enabled?

Comment: Yes. You can check that by hovering mouse over disabled ribbon buttons.

Comment: Yeah, and what I wanted to achieve is to display the hint ONLY when the action is disabled.